# Filter a List of objects using Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects. I want to create another list in which to add certain objects from the created list. I want to use Stream-filter, but I don't understand where I'm wrong. Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Initial list:

```
 final List<CategoryModel> categoryList = doSearch(query, params, CategoryModel.class);
```

List with objects filtered from first list:

```
List<CategoryModel> sitemapList = (List<CategoryModel>) categoryList.stream().filter(categoryModel -> selectCategoryForSitemap(categoryModel));
```

Function for filter objects:

```
private boolean selectCategoryForSitemap(CategoryModel categoryModel){
    if(categoryModel.getMetaRobots() != null) {
        if (categoryModel.getMetaRobots() == CmsRobotTag.INDEX_FOLLOW || categoryModel.getMetaRobots() == CmsRobotTag.INDEX_NOFOLLOW) {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }else if (categoryModel instanceof BrandCategoryModel || categoryModel instanceof CategoryModel) {
        if(!categoryModel.getCode().equals("1")) {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }
    return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<CategoryModel> sitemapList = categoryList.stream()
    .filter(categoryModel -> selectCategoryForSitemap(categoryModel))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can't just cast stream to something.

If you want to get result you have to call one of  *terminal operation*. In this case you need `collect`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you need to put a collector on the stream to return a list. But there may be additional problems that aren't as obvious.

```
List<CategoryModel> sitemapList = categoryList.stream()
                .filter(categoryModel -> selectCategoryForSitemap(
                        categoryModel)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```